# Render list from (unkown deep) multidimensional object in Vue

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

Imagine a JSON object of the following structure:

```json
{
  "dimension-1": {
    "value1": "",
    "value2": "",
    "value3": "",
    "value4": ""
  },
  "dimension-2": {
    "value1": "",
    "value2": "",
    "value3": "",
    "value4": "",
    "dimension-2.1": {
      "value1": "",
      "dimension-2.2": {
        "value1": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The object can have an unlimited number of nestings and the number is **unknown**.

What I want to create is a list that represents the JSON object by using the [Vue List Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) feature or something similar (if possible). At the end I would receive something like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    dimension-1
    <ul>
      <li>value-1</li>
      <li>value-2</li>
      <li>value-3</li>
      <li>value-4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    dimension-2
    <ul>
      <li>value-1</li>
      <li>value-2</li>
      <li>value-3</li>
      <li>value-4</li>
      <li>
        dimension-2.1
        <ul>
          <li>value-1</li>
          <li>
            dimension-2.2
            <ul>
              <li>value1</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

With normal JS this is quite easy to do:

```js
const object = {
  "dimension-1": {
    "value1": "",
    "value2": "",
    "value3": "",
    "value4": ""
  },
  "dimension-2": {
    "value1": "",
    "value2": "",
    "value3": "",
    "value4": "",
    "dimension-2.1": {
      "value1": "",
      "dimension-2.2": {
        "value1": ""
      }
    }
  }
}

function createHTML(json, isArray) {

  var html = '<ul>';
  for (var key in json) {
    if (typeof json[key] == 'object') {

      html += '<li>' + (!isArray ? '<strong>' + key + '</strong>' : '') + '</li>' + createHTML(json[key], (json[key] instanceof Array ? 1 : 0));
    } else {
      html += '<li>' + key + '</li>';
    }
  }
  return html + '</ul>';

}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = createHTML(object, false);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

[Copied and changed from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367907/create-nested-list-dynamically-from-json-object)

However, this will obviously not work because of this part `html += '<li>' + (!isArray ? '<strong>' + key + '</strong>' : '') + '</li>' + -->createHTML(json[key], (json[key] instanceof Array ? 1 : 0))<--;`.

So what is the solution to my problem or an alternative?

Comment: take a look here https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/10/23/vue-js-tree-menu-recursive-components/

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is the same as the JavaScript snippet you made. You just need to swap the `document.getElementById` part with a proper Vue `ref`.

For instance:

```
<template>
   <div>
      <ul ref="myList"></ul>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Example",
  mounted() {
     const myList = this.$refs.myList;
     myList.innerHTML = "<li>One element</li>";
  }
};
</script>
```

Not ideal because you lose the Vue part there but quick and easy.
If you want to get more in detail in building this recursive list you can check this out: https://alligator.io/vuejs/recursive-components/